# No such host is known using AquaQ

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I am trying to set up a production environment for KDB using AquaQ.

I have set up the appropriate Environment Variables and modified the process.csv  file to have my IP in it.  When I try and load torq.q I get the error:

> cannot create alias on windows os.

Below is what's in the error log following

> 2014.12.30D15:40:06.203625000|hoffmanpc|hdb2|ERR|fileload|failed to load C:\TORQFULL\TORQ\src\code/handlers/logusage.q : c: No such host is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terry you were right actually.  It turns out q requires this "/" in paths not "\".  I had "\" in the path for the environment variables. Johnny Press answered this for me [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/personal-kdbplus/MmMIsrdcD0U)

Comment: Yep, saw it. That's good! Maybe mark one of these answers/comments as "solution", for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You're running on windows right? As far as I'm aware, TorQ is specifically designed and tested for Linux and OSX, not windows.

Seems the error above is due to the file paths having forward slashes vs backslashes. If you could manually fix the hard-coded filepaths to be in windows format it might work. Best best is to contact AquaQ themselves

Comment: Thanks Terry, the slashes are actually interchangeable.  I just tried to load a q script with both slashes and it worked.  In their documentation they have stated it works on windows with kdb+3.1 and 2.8 and I am running 3.2 so I will downgrade and check. Cheers